# Can foreign key references contain NULL values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, reference, foreign-keys, primary-key

As an example

```
create table indexing_table
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
);
```

Is there a difference between the following tables?

Table 1:

```
create table referencing_table
(
  indexing_table_id INTEGER references indexing_table
);
```

Table 2:

```
create table referencing_table
(
  indexing_table_id INTEGER references indexing_table NOT NULL
);
```

Alternatively, in the case of Table 1, where there is no `NOT NULL` constraint, are we allowed to insert records containing `NULL` values?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For table 1, this INSERT statement will succeed. If you run it 100 times, it will succeed 100 times.

```
insert into referencing_table values (null);
```

The same INSERT statement will fail on table 2.

```
ERROR:  null value in column "indexing_table_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null).
```

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes you want a foreign keyed column to be nullable because it is not required (just as not every **citizen** in a citizens table went to a university, so a `university_id` column can be null). In other cases, the column should not be null, just as every **student** lshould be associated with a `university_id`.

Therefore, the two `referencing_table`s you describe are actually very different, if you consider what you are trying to achieve.